# Tracing stdout and stderr in Tcl

Tags: tcl, stdout, trace, stderr

I'm not sure if this absurd. Isn't it possible to `trace` the read and write of `stdout` and `stderr` in Tcl?

I have tried the below and found no clue.

```
% proc tracer {varname args} {
    upvar #0 $varname var
    puts "$varname value : $var"
}
% trace add variable stdout read tracer
% trace add variable stdout write tracer
% puts stdout hai
hai
% puts hai
hai
% trace add variable stderr write tracer
% trace add variable stderr read tracer
% puts hai
hai
% puts stderr hai
hai
```

As per the man page of `puts`, if no `channelId` is specified for `puts` command, then it defaults to `stdout` which means even with `puts hai`, `stdout` will be accessed. Right ? (Though it is not working even with the argument as `stdout` or `stderr`)

Comment: Um, `stdout` and `stderr` are channels, not variables... I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your attempted solution is that `stdout`, `stderr` and `stdin` are not variables but names of the so-called "channels".
In essence, they're in a separated namespace (not a namespace operated by the `namespace` Tcl command!): you can get a list of them using the `chan names` command but you can't, say, `rename` a channel, or assign a value to it or `unset` it: these operations simply have no sense on channels and will affect a variable by that name instead.

An approach to trace a channel is to actually subvert it with another—"script-level"—channel and "proxy" all operations.  This trick uses a lesser-known Tcl's feature: when you close one of Tcl's standard channels and immediately open a channel (no matter if "real" or "script-level"), that will gets registered in place of that standard channel just closed.  Hence if we close a standard channel and immediately create our own "proxy" channel in its place we hence subvert that standard channel.

Those "script-level" ("reflected") channels require Tcl ≥ 8.5.

Here's a sketch of subverting `stdout` which requires Linux (for `/proc/self/fd/<fileno>` support).

```
proc traceChan {cmd chan args} {
    global stdout

    puts stderr "Trace on $chan; cmd=$cmd; args=$args"

    switch -- $cmd {
        initialize {
            return [list initialize finalize watch write configure cget cgetall]
        }
        finalize {
            chan close $stdout
        }
        watch {
            # FIXME: not implemented
        }
        write {
            set data [lindex $args 0]
            chan puts -nonewline $stdout $data
            return [string length $data]
        }
        configure {
            return [chan config $stdout {*}$args]
        }
        cget {
            return [chan cget $stdout {*}$args
        }
        cgetall {
            return [chan configure $stdout]
        }
    }
}

set fn [file readlink /proc/self/fd/1]
set conf [chan config stdout]
chan close stdout
chan create write ::traceChan
set stdout [open $fn w]
chan configure stdout {*}$conf

puts [chan names]
puts test
chan flush stdout
chan close stdout
```

On my system it botches terminal settings (`stdout` is connected to a terminal), and requires me to execute `reset` followed by `stty sane` after the script exits but at least it does the job done.

Actual problems with this script:

- In fact we lie about the number of bytes written: we have no idea how many bytes the underlying `stdout` channel will write as it depends on a number of things.
- We don't handle channel events at all.

These problems can be addressed by writing a C module implementing such a proxying: with the C API, you would have access to the underlying file descriptor/handle (so no requirement for `/proc/self/fd/...`) and a Tcl object wrapping it (so you could possibly just *clone* it right away) and know how many bytes were written by the underlying channel.

---

Oh, and note that if you're fine with throwing the data sent by the script to the subverted standard channels away, just do no dances with re-opening the real underlying file, closing it, writing data to it etc.  The solution will then boild down to performing `chan create` immediately after `chan close` and tracing writes in the tracing procedure.  In response to the `write` call your tracing routine will still need to return a number of bytes thrown away.

---

Please also read the [`chan`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/chan.htm) and [`refchan`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/refchan.htm) manual pages.

Comment: Doing the interception by pushing a logging transform (Tcl 8.6 feature) would possible. And a lot cleaner.